# Boton javascript para obtener un token de Trello

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, botón

estoy tratando obtener mi token de trello mediante esta función de javascript que se ejecuta al pulsar un botón, recoge una key, llama a la api de trello para obtener un token y después envía la apikey y el token. Al incluir la llamada a la api de Trello dejo de funcionar, no se que estoy haciendo mal, alguna sugerencia?
Segun la API de Trello debería saltar una ventana emergente para permitir el acceso, lo probé la función TrelloAuthorize en el HTML y sí lo hace.

```
  $('#btn').click(function() {

        var apikey = document.getElementById("login").value;

        //Obtengo el Token de Trello
    $(window).load(function(){
        Trello.authorize({
            name: "Task Slayer",
            type: "popup",
            interactive: true,
            expiration: "never",
            success: function () { onTrelloAuthorizeSuccessful(); },
            scope: { write: true, read: true },
        });

        // Save the token after success call
        function onTrelloAuthorizeSuccessful(var apikey) {   
        var token = Trello.token();

            return token
        }
    });
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            // Nombre de la propiedad que que recibe el valor de x en el backend
            api_key: apikey,
            token:onTrelloAuthorizeSuccessful()

        },
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/HelloSpringMVC/hello',
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          // Hacer algo con la respuesta

        },
        error: function(e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el codigo que publicas, encuentro 2 detalles:

1. Estas incluyendo la rutina de `Trello.authorize()` dentro de un `.load()` de `jQuery`, lo cual es incorrecto.
2. La función `onTrelloAuthorizeSuccessful()`
   espera un parámetro que nunca es pasado a la rutina, y aunque esto
   no afecta la funcionalidad del programa debes revisar con claridad
   lo que quieres hacer.

prueba comentar el `.load()` de `jQuery`, de la siguiente manera:

```js
  $('#btn').click(function() {

        var apikey = document.getElementById("login").value;

        //Obtengo el Token de Trello
//        $(window).load(function(){     <-- comenta esta linea
        Trello.authorize({
            name: "Task Slayer",
            type: "popup",
            interactive: true,
            expiration: "never",
            success: function () { onTrelloAuthorizeSuccessful(); },
            scope: { write: true, read: true },
        });

        // Save the token after success call
        function onTrelloAuthorizeSuccessful(var apikey) {   // apikey nunca es pasado a la rutina
        var token = Trello.token();

            return token
        }
//        });                            <-- Comenta esta otra linea
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            // Nombre de la propiedad que que recibe el valor de x en el backend
            api_key: apikey,
            token:onTrelloAuthorizeSuccessful()

        },
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/HelloSpringMVC/hello',
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          // Hacer algo con la respuesta

        },
        error: function(e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      });

    });
```

Comment: Gracias, me fue muy útil